# unixODBC could not be found

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to install psqlODBC using the Stack builder on Ubuntu 16.04 and I've done

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev unixodbc-bin unixodbc
```

It says:

```
unixODBC could not be found
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't

```
sudo apt-get install odbc-postgresql
```

enough if you want the psqlODBC ?